# replicate CSV.generate_line behaviour of ruby 1.8.7 in ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby, csv

ruby 1.9 now uses fastercsv, but how do i replicate the generate_line behaviour of ruby 1.8.7 ?

```
ruby-1.8.7-p334 :010 > require 'csv'
 => true
ruby-1.8.7-p334 :010 > CSV.generate_line(["ab","cd"], "\t")
 => "ab\tcd"

ruby-1.9.2-p180 :002 > require 'csv'
 => true
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :007 > CSV.generate_line(["ab","cd"], :row_sep => ?\t)
 => "ab,cd\t"
```

Notice how `\t` is between the two array items in ruby 1.8.7 and at last in `1.9.2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use col_sep instead. row_sep is the row separator:

```
CSV.generate_line(["ab","cd"], :col_sep => ?\t)
=> "ab\tcd\n"
```

or

```
CSV.generate_line(["ab","cd"], :col_sep => ?\t, :row_sep => '')
=> "ab\tcd"
```

You can find more details and additional options in the [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/csv/rdoc/classes/CSV.html#M000190).

Answer (score 1):

CSV.generate_line(['a','b','c'],:col_sep=>"\t")